# How can I add .m2 repository jars or maven dependency jars in a freestyle project in jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a maven project on my local system, but I created a freestyle project in jenkins and gave its the workspace directory as of my project.
Being new to jenkins, I am wondering how to add maven repository jars to a freestyle project's classpath while writing its batch file to execute the project, in such a way that all the jars which are in recursive directories

> C:\users\xyz\.m2\repository\*

come in the path while building the project. I don't know whether it is possible or not without any hassle, but when we create a maven project in jenkins it automatically takes all the repository jars in the build path. So there must be a way around rather than putting those libraries manually into the build path. I have searched so much on google but nothing popped up.

Any input would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). This will prepare environment to be built before the job run. So in your case adding the path can also be done using this one. If you are running the jenkins on windows machine, doing this will do the trick. Or if you are running on Linux please feel free to explore or comment here again.

[image: Jenkins Windows Path EnvInject Plugin Adding]

Comment: Thanks @Madhava for replying..I installed this plugin and I tried giving path to my repository (C:\users\xyz\.m2\repository), it didn't work. Also I tried to add my project in the path, it is not working.

Comment: yeah Madhava I am using windows 10

Comment: you can add all these directly into the windows classpath right?? Whats stopping you from doing this??

Comment: And btw its all depends upon the maven not jenkins related. If you can able to do that using eclipse or command line then, you can do it in jenkins also without any other extra config.